# regex: split by brackets ignore nested brackets

Tags: java, regex, parsing, logging, garbage-collection

I'm trying to parse some Java GC logs and I'm having trouble getting some times out.

The format is as follows:

```
[GC x.xxx: [ParNew: ...K->...K(...K), y.yyyyyy secs] ...->...K(...), z.zzzzzz secs]
```

I need to get y.yyyyyy secs and z.zzzzzz secs out. The format isn't always this exact. I pretty much need the GC time and ParNew times which are always at the end of their respective brackets. (ParNew bracket is nested inside the GC bracket and there are sometimes even more nested brackets)

I've found some RegEx for nested parentheses instead of brackets but I'm having trouble converting it to brackets.

Here's the RegEx for parentheses:

```
(?<=\()(?:[^()]+|\([^)]+\))+
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

***EDIT***

Here is another format:

```
2015-06-18T16:12:52.546-0400: 230.643: 
[Full GC 230.643: [CMS2015-06-18T16:13:01.671-0400: 239.767: [CMS-
concurrent-mark: 9.342/9.342 secs] 
[Times: user=9.41 sys=0.02, real=9.34 secs (concurrent mode failure):
 5392703K->5392703K(5392704K), 26.8121270 secs] 6179135K-
>6073557K(6179136K), [CMS Perm : 32344K->32344K(262144K)], 26.8122780 secs] 
[Times: user=25.86 sys=0.03, real=26.81 secs]
```

Here I need the time for the `[CMS2015-06-18...` bracket which is `26.8121270 secs`.

***EDIT 2***

Here is an actual example of the ParNew format:

```
2015-06-18T16:09:03.284-0400: 1.381: [GC 1.381: [ParNew: 674112K-
>112320K(786432K), 4.5234120 secs] 674112K->541274K(6179136K), 
4.5235390 secs] [Times: user=12.53 sys=0.77, real=4.52 secs]
```

Here I need the `4.5235390 secs` time of `ParNew:`

These two formats are the main formats I need to parse.

Comment: This is always a useful site for testing Regexes: https://regex101.com/ It pretty clearly explains what is happening in every part of the regex. Apart from that, what's the trouble you're having for converting it?

Comment: Are the literal strings `secs` part of the format?

Comment: Couldn't you simply do `([0-9]\.[0-9]+ secs).*([0-9]\.[0-9]+ secs)`? Both strings you are hoping to catch are now in groups 1 and 2.

Comment: @DevonParsons , yes secs are part of the format

Comment: There are other secs in the log file that I don't care about capturing. I need to tie y.yyyyyy secs with ParNew and z.zzzzzz secs with the GC event @ShellFish

Comment: So, you want the text directly following the opening bracket, and then the text just before the closing bracket? Unfortunately, I believe that's impossible to do using pure Regex, and I'm not sure PHP can do it. The reason for this is that pure Regex has no way to express an equal number of opening and closing brackets, so it has no way of knowing if the closing bracket belongs to the opening bracket you matched.

Comment: This is not possible, since you can't repeat 'recursive' brackets. If you indeed can have a variable amount of nested brackets, you'll need to actually parse these brackets to split them, running a simple regex on each nested bracket. You could use a regex like `\[[^[]*?\]` to match the deepest matching brackets, remove those from the string, and then run that again, until you have found all matching brackets without their nested brackets.

Comment: @ErikDolor: php regex (as Perl & Ruby regex) is able to describe nested structures because recursive patterns are possible (you can refer to a subpattern). It's possible with .net regex too since it has a kind of counter for each capture group. Unfortunately Java regex doesn't have one of these two features. However if there is a fixed maximum level of nesting, it is possible.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Really? That's interesting, a good reason to learn either of those languages at least on a basic level. That would remove most of the limits of Regexes.

Comment: *" trying to parse some Java GC logs"* have you considered looking at [GCViewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer)'s log parser? Might avoid redundant work.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on where your other brackets can be.

I made this, assuming more brackets can be nested inside of `ParNew:` bracket

`(?<=\[GC)(?:.*)(?:\[ParNew.*?)(?:(?:\[.*\]).*?)*(\d+(?:\.\d+)? secs)\].*?(\d+(?:\.\d+)? secs)`

https://regex101.com/r/yZ6cF3/1

I added some examples with extra nested brackets, which also end with `x.xxx secs` and are not captured.

The tricky part is `(?:(?:\[.*\]).*?)*`, which adds the option to have any amount of brackets inside but ignore them.

Here is a demo with your given example `(?<=GC)(?:.*)(?:\[(?:ParNew|CMS20.*?):.*?)(?:(?:\[.*\]).*?)*(\d+(?:\.\d+)? secs)\].*?(\d+(?:\.\d+)? secs)(?:\])(?:(?:[.*])*)`: https://regex101.com/r/iY9wQ1/2

Note that I added `(?:ParNew|CMS20.*?)` or any other start of a variable that you're interested in. Without doing that, there's no guarantee it will work.

Comment: It also worked for your example, but you have to add the variable you need to the "ParNew" part. The way i wrote it I assumed you needed 2 results, so it assumes $2 is the GC number, even though your example didn't have any.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The two formats I gave are both possible. For the first format I need the ParNew time and the second format I need the CMS2015-... time. In the beginning of the bracket is the name of the field and at the end is the time it took. Thanks again. I'll try modifying to include the CMS2015- field

Comment: I wrote an edit, you can see how you can do it there. It still might need slight configuring (to avoid $2 result when you don't need), but it should give you the idea.

Comment: Perfect! I think it works. The times seem to repeat for some reason but that might be with how I implemented it in Java. Thanks again. It was a big help

Answer (score 0):

This regex works for me:

```
([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(?=\W*secs])
```

[Here's an example](https://regex101.com/r/lT8wR0/1). In this case, each number will be in a capturing group.

What this regex does, basically, is:

- a capturing group for a decimal number (one or more digits, a literal period, followed by one or more digits)
- a lookahead for:

  - One or more whitespaces
  - The literal text `sec]`

Since you say it's not always in this exact format, I assumed that meant that the spaces between the number and 'secs' could differ. If you meant some other part that can change, please let us know, and I'll offer a modified regex.

Comment: The spaces between number and 'secs' stay the same. Here is how it could differ:

2015-06-18T16:12:52.546-0400: 230.643: [Full GC 230.643: [CMS2015-06-18T16:13:01.671-0400: 239.767: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 9.342/9.342 secs] [Times: user=9.41 sys=0.02, real=9.34 secs] 
 (concurrent mode failure): 5392703K->5392703K(5392704K), 26.8121270 secs] 6179135K->6073557K(6179136K), [CMS Perm : 32344K->32344K(262144K)], 26.8122780 secs] [Times: user=25.86 sys=0.03, real=26.81 secs] 

Now I need the [CMS2015-06-18T16:13:01.671-0400: 239.767 time of 26.8121270 secs.

Comment: It definitely is. But if I understand correctly, you simply want all decimals, followed by `secs]`. Am I right, or is there more you need to capture (e.g. the `secs` part)?

Comment: In cases like this, it's always essential to be able to clearly get an idea of what you're really trying to capture. In this case, it could be what I just proposed above (in this comment). Try not to look at the target text as a whole; Attempt to find the similarities and patterns in only the part you need to capture, and the text directly surrounding it.

Comment: Sorry about the confusing, I edited my initial question. See if that helps.

Comment: I don't necessarly want all decimals, just specific ones. I also need to tie them to their opening bracket names. So the ParNew time has to be tied to y.yyyyyy secs and GC time has to be tied to z.zzzzzz secs. There could be other secs and times there as well. I included an actual example in the edit I made.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the times after the string "real" then this works in C# (I am not a Java person)

```
 (?ixs)(?<=real\s{0,}=\s{0,})\d{1,}(\.\d{1,})*? \s{1,}secs
```

this gives me 2 values back: 9.34 and 26.81